# azure-devops-pipelines, Trigger another pipeline when finished this pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

There are two pipelines like this.

'first-pipeline'

```
trigger: none
         
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true 

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm i -g @angular/cli@14.2.10
    npm install
    ng build app --configuration=production --output-hashing=all
    ng build mobile --configuration=production --output-hashing=all
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- script: |
    git config --global user.email "test"
    git config --global user.name "test"
    npm version $(version) -m "Bump version to $(version)"
    git tag -a v$(version)
    git push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName) -q
    git push origin v$(version)
  displayName: 'Increase Version'
  condition: succeeded()
```

'second-pipeline' triggered automatically after finishing first-pipeline

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: firstPipeline
      source: first-pipeline
      trigger: true

steps:

- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm i -g @angular/cli@14.2.10
    npm install
    ng build app --configuration=production --output-hashing=all
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

From first-pipeline, a new commit is created. (version up)
But, second-pipeline is built by the previous commit.

I want second-pipeline to be built by a new commit created first-pipeline.

What is the problem with my pipeline?